# Can I safely use both the "to" and "onClick" props on a React Router Link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd love to keep the benefits of using the default routing mechanism via the `to` prop, but also add additional logging logic for when the link gets clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What logic do you want to achieve? And what's stopping you from adding `onClick` handler to `Link` component?

```
<Link to="/" onClick={event => { alert('home') }}>Home</Link>
```

Another possible option would be to `Link` to another component where you could put whatever logic inside the lifecycle method like `componentDidMount()`.

[Go to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-dream-m9r49)

Answering your question, there is a support for `onClick` event in the [source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v5.1.2/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L32). So I guess it's totally fine.

Comment: The question was whether this is safe (performance trade off, history consistency etc), not if I can do it. I know you can add both props and the app doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

If the treatment depends on the route and not the link you can add the click handler to the render property of Route, else assign the handler to onClick property of the Link.

```
<Route 
   path="home"
   render={props=>{
                 //Handler function
                 this.handler();
                 //Component to render
                 return <Home/>; 
                 }}
/>
```